# Any way to declare a size/partial border to a box?

Tags: css, border

Any way to declare a size/partial border to a box in CSS? For example a box with `350px` that only shows a border-bottom in its firsts `60px`. I think that might be very useful.

Examples:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Not really. But it's very easy to achieve the effect in a way that degrades gracefully and requires no superfluous markup:

```css
div {
  width: 350px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightgray;
  position: relative;
  margin: 20px;
}

div:after {
  content: '';
  width: 60px;
  height: 4px;
  background: gray;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -4px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Nothing like being marked the right answer without +1'd. But I +1'd you! This was a perfect solution for my problem. Thanks! [edit] I guess you could have been +1'd be OP and -1'd by someone else. Oh well. I appreciate your answer, and that's all that matters, right ;-)

Comment: How do you get this to be in the center, like in his second example?

Comment: I should add, when the parent element is a fluid-width inline-block element. Obviously when it's fixed width it's easy.

Comment: Nevermind, I got the effect I wanted - http://dabblet.com/gist/e5a78f2d4bf50b6be4d3. It's a shame the `::outside` and `::inside` pseudo-elements aren't available yet, I hate putting in markup just for styling, but I don't think there is any other way.

Comment: This works! To use it with React, you cannot use `content` in `:after` as inline style or JSS, but it works fine using styled components.

Answer (score 34):

I know, this is already solved and pixels were requested. However, I just wanted to share something...

Partly underlined text elements can easily achieved by using `display:table` or `display:inline-block`

<sup>(I just don't use `display:inline-block` because, yeah you know, the awkward `4px`-gap).</sup>

### Textual Elements

```css
h1 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f00;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<h1>Foo is not equal to bar</h1>
```

**Centering**, `display:table` makes it impossible to center the element with `text-align:center`.
Let's work around with `margin:auto`...

```css
h1 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f00;
  display: table;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<h1>Foo is not equal to bar</h1>
```

**Well**, that's nice, but it's not **partially**.
As [bookcasey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8837382/1250044) already introduced, pseudo-elements are worth gold.

```css
h1 {
  display: table;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

h1:after {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f00;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Foo is not equal to bar</h1>
```

**Offset**, the underline is left aligned right now. To center it, just push the pseudo-element the half of its `width` (`50% / 2 = 25%`) to the right.

```css
h1 {
  display: table;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

h1:after {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f00;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin-left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<h1>Foo is not equal to bar</h1>
```

...as [davidmatas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835142/any-way-to-declare-a-size-partial-border-to-a-box/37338297?noredirect=1#comment62200908_37338297) commented, using `margin:auto` is sometimes more practical, than calculating the `margin`-offset by hand.

So, we can align the underline to the left, right or center (without knowing the current `width`) by using one of these combinations:

- **Left**: `margin-right: auto` <sub>(or just leave it off)</sub>
- **Middle**: `margin: auto`
- **Right**: `margin-left: auto`

---

**Full example**

```css
.underline {
  display: table;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.underline:after {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f00;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
}

.underline--left:after {
  margin-right: auto; /* ...or just leave it off */
}

.underline--center:after {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.underline--right:after {
  margin-left: auto
}
```

```html
<h1 class="underline underline--left">Foo is not equal to bar</h1>
<h1 class="underline underline--center">Foo is not equal to bar</h1>
<h1 class="underline underline--right">Foo is not equal to bar</h1>
```

### Block-Level Elements

This can easily be adopted, so that we can use block-level elements. The trick is to set the pseudo-elements height to the same height as its *real* element (simply `height:100%`):

```css
div {
  background-color: #eee;
  display: table;
  height: 100px;
  width: 350px;
}
div:after {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #666;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Great answer. For the `:after` I like more a `margin: 0 auto` approach instead the `margin-left: 25%` because it will work with any width you declare without need to do maths.

Comment: @davidmatas Good point! I've just used the *mathy-way* to clarify how to position it manually by hand. With this example anyone could understand how to align it left/center/right. Anyway, I will add the `auto`-*simplificator* :)

Answer (score 32):

Here is another solution that rely on `linear-gradient` where you can easily create any kind of line you want. You can also have multiple lines (on each side for example) by using multiple background:

```css
.box1 {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to right, transparent 20%, #000 20%, #000 40%, transparent 40%) 0 100% / 100% 3px no-repeat, 
    #ccc
}

.box2 {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to right, transparent 20%, red 20%, red 80%, transparent 80%) 0 100% / 100% 2px no-repeat, 
    #ccc
}

.box3{
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to right, transparent 20%, red 20%, red 80%, transparent 80%) 0 100% / 100% 2px no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(to right, transparent 30%, blue 30%, blue 70%, transparent 70%) 0 0 / 100% 2px no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 30%, brown 30%, brown 70%, transparent 70%) 0 0 / 3px 100% no-repeat,
    linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 20%, orange 20%, orange 70%, transparent 70%) 100% 0 / 3px 100% no-repeat,
  #ccc
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
  Box1
</div>
<div class="box2">
  Box2
</div>
<div class="box3">
  Box3
</div>
```

Here is another syntax to achieve the same as above:

```css
.box1 {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  background: 
   linear-gradient(#000 0 0) top /40% 3px no-repeat, 
   #ccc
}

.box2 {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(red 0 0) bottom/ 60% 2px no-repeat, 
    #ccc;
}

.box3{
  width: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  text-align: center;
  background: 
   linear-gradient(red 0 0)bottom left/ 60% 2px,
   linear-gradient(blue 0 0) 60% 0 / 40% 2px,
   linear-gradient(brown 0 0) left/ 3px 30%,
   linear-gradient(orange 0 0) right / 3px 40%,
   #ccc;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1">
  Box1
</div>
<div class="box2">
  Box2
</div>
<div class="box3">
  Box3
</div>
```

Comment: Wow... I've been fiddling for hours to find a way to have only the upper left and upper right corner of an "implied" box showing. :before and :after was too limited, it messed up the object's positioning. This is a brilliant solution!

Comment: Some background information on why and how this works: https://www.webfx.com/blog/web-design/background-css-shorthand/

Comment: It clips the corner borders if used with `border-radius`

Comment: Great solution. I wonder how to stick a text or an image in the middle of each line.

Answer (score 2):

I used a grid to build draw some of the borders.

See [here](https://github.com/juanpastas/partial_border).

Code:

```css
/* ungrid without mobile */

.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.col {
  display: table-cell;
}


/* things to change */

.row {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
}

.mid.row>.col {
  height: 150px;
}


/* draw box and align text */

.col {
  text-align: center;
}

.top.left.col {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.top.right.col {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.bottom.left.col {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}

.bottom.right.col {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.mid.row>.col {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.top.center.col {
  position: relative;
  top: -0.5em;
}

.bottom.center.col {
  position: relative;
  bottom: -0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="top left col"></div>
  <div class="top center col">Top</div>
  <div class="top right col"></div>
</div>
<div class="mid row">
  <div class="col">Mid</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="bottom left col"></div>
  <div class="bottom center col">Bottom</div>
  <div class="bottom right col"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen since the person edited the code, the comment is obsolete

Answer (score -1):

CSS does not support partial borders. You'd need to use an adjacent element to simulate this.

Comment: Or a pseudo-element, which you can do entirely with CSS and not add any markup, as illustrated by the answers above

Answer (score -1):

Been playing a bit around with your solutions and came up with that.

I'd appreciate your comments and thoughts.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>test file</title>
  <style>
    #box {
      background-color: gray;
      position: relative;
      left: 10px;
      top: 10px;
      height: 180px;
      width: 380px;
    }
    
    #grad1 {
      position: absolute;
      left: -10px;
      top: -10px;
      height: 40px;
      width: 2px;
      background-image: linear-gradient(red, red);
    }
    
    #grad2 {
      position: absolute;
      left: -10px;
      top: -10px;
      height: 2px;
      width: 40px;
      background-image: linear-gradient(red, red);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="box">
    <div id="grad1"></div>
    <div id="grad2"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```