# CSS border - box without corners

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to create borders like the one on the image? Just with css border attributes. End result would be boxes without the corners. I don't want to add additional html elements. I would like to just add css border information to each li element.

Assume that this is a ul - li list.

[image: sample layout]

Comment: See [this very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835142/any-way-to-declare-a-size-partial-border-to-a-box) for a potential answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is my attempt with the use of `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements and some CSS3 selectors

```
li{
    position: relative;
}
/* Add bottom border for all boxes except the last two */
li:not(:nth-last-child(2)):not(:last-child):after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 50%;
    left: 25%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
/* Add right border for all odd indexed boxes (1,3,5...) */
li:nth-child(2n+1):before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    height: 50%;
    top: 25%;
    width: 2px;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/gq03p4k2/)**

---

You could also emulate the border with `box-shadow`, eliminating the need for the pseudo elements but this approach would only be fit if your boxes are of fixed size since you can't have responsive shadows.

```
li:not(:nth-last-child(2)):not(:last-child){
   box-shadow: 0 53px 9px -56px #000;
}
li:not(:nth-last-child(2)):not(:last-child):nth-child(2n+1){
   box-shadow: 0 53px 9px -56px #000, 53px 0px 9px -56px #000;
}
li:nth-child(2n+1){
    box-shadow: 53px 0px 9px -56px #000;
}
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/gq03p4k2/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

You will have to play around with some css techniques, but I think something with `:after` might do the trick...

Here's a sample example of a list item with a half size's bottom border:

http://jsfiddle.net/meho9ncf/

```
ul li:after {
    content: "";
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 25%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. This works perfect for the bottom border. But I couldn't make it work for the right border.

Comment: It would be the same, just setting `width: 100%; height: 50%; margin-top: 25%;` and removing `margin-left`