# Unusual border css

Tags: html, css

How to do border with adaptive height like this?

Can it be pure css?

https://pp.vk.me/c639230/v639230336/9dce/Q28JR-9v-Lc.jpg

Comment: It's easy. Read [ask] and create a [mcve]. And yes, it can be done with `CSS` alone. If you search properly, you'll find it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to declare a size/partial border to a box?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835142/any-way-to-declare-a-size-partial-border-to-a-box)

Answer (score 1):

I have created a sample code on the following CodePen. http://codepen.io/jaymanpandya/pen/pRXExJ\

HTML

```
<div class='border'>
  <h1 class='title'>What we do</h1>

  <div class='item-chunk'>
    <p>Image tag comes here</p>
    <h2>Design</h2>
    <p>Sed egestas, ante et vulputate volutpat, eros pede semper est, vitae luctus metus libero eu augue. Morbi purus libero, faucibus adipiscing, commodo quis, gravida id, est. Sed lectus. Praesent elementum hendrerit tortor. Sed semper lorem at felis. Vestibulum volutpat, lacus a ultrices sagittis, mi neque euismod dui, eu pulvinar nunc sapien ornare nisl. Phasellus pede arcu, dapibus eu, fermentum et, dapibus sed, urna.</p>
  </div>

  <div class='item-chunk'>
    <p>Image tag comes here</p>
    <h2>Development</h2>
    <p>Sed egestas, ante et vulputate volutpat, eros pede semper est, vitae luctus metus libero eu augue. Morbi purus libero, faucibus adipiscing, commodo quis, gravida id, est. Sed lectus. Praesent elementum hendrerit tortor. Sed semper lorem at felis. Vestibulum volutpat, lacus a ultrices sagittis, mi neque euismod dui, eu pulvinar nunc sapien ornare nisl. Phasellus pede arcu, dapibus eu, fermentum et, dapibus sed, urna.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  padding:5%;
}

.border {
  width:500px;
  margin:auto;
  border:1px solid #333;
  padding:1% 2%;
}

.title {
  width:250px;
  font-size:24px;
  font-family:Arial;
  background:#fff;
  text-align:center;
  margin:-30px auto auto;
}

.item-chunk {
  text-align:center;
  padding:5% 0;
}
```

It has a covering div with class name 'border' which has an adaptive height. I have cheated the gap in top border by shifting the h1 tag upwards by negative margin and giving it a white background.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: is it possible to set transparent title background?

Comment: If you would set transparent background for title. You will be able to see the border striking through the title. It's not the approach that I would take, if I would have been in your shoes.