# CSS Border DIV as a Shape

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a `div` element containing some text. I would like to add a border to the top left and bottom right corners in order to create a shield or crest outline effect, similar to the following;

[image]

I would also like the border to be responsive if possible. I am having some difficulty figuring out how to do this.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/johnny_s/kfcpxyex/) is a link to the fiddle I have created.

My code so far is;

```css
#mainDiv {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  border-top: 10px solid black;
  background: #3beadc;
}

.borderLeft {
  border-left: 10px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainDiv">
  <div class="borderLeft">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris suscipit quis est vel fringilla. Quisque eget tellus sed est vulputate varius. Quisque scelerisque lobortis molestie. Ut libero lorem, consequat quis commodo et, porttitor et sapien.
      Donec tristique purus eget nunc tincidunt ornare. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla consequat pellentesque pharetra. Donec imperdiet ex metus. Vestibulum nulla ligula, semper vel odio ut, ornare pellentesque arcu. Sed
      neque lectus, fermentum non ultricies id, sollicitudin eget turpis.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps an overlapping `div` method like this one is a could place to start. Though I'm struggling to remove the top right and bottom left corners. http://jsfiddle.net/samtwc/y3EfP/991/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to declare a size/partial border to a box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835142/any-way-to-declare-a-size-partial-border-to-a-box)

Comment: OP check my answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `:before` and `:after` pseudoelements to create small borders. Maybe not the best way, but it works:

```css
#mainDiv {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  background: #3beadc;
  border-radius: 0 0 100px 0;
}

#mainDiv:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-top: 10px solid black;
  border-left: 10px solid black;
}

#mainDiv:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-bottom: 10px solid black;
  border-right: 10px solid black;
  border-radius: 0 0 100px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainDiv">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris suscipit quis est vel fringilla. Quisque eget tellus sed est vulputate varius. Quisque scelerisque lobortis molestie. Ut libero lorem, consequat quis commodo et, porttitor et sapien.
      Donec tristique purus eget nunc tincidunt ornare. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla consequat pellentesque pharetra. Donec imperdiet ex metus. Vestibulum nulla ligula, semper vel odio ut, ornare pellentesque arcu. Sed
      neque lectus, fermentum non ultricies id, sollicitudin eget turpis.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! Why might it not be the best way?

Comment: It might cover onclick functions because elements go on top of the other.

Comment: Actually I think it is, pseudo-elements are very useful to do things like that one. Edit : Sergio is right about the click events.

Comment: pseudo-elements are probably your best means since it avoids unnecessary HTML. my only real concern would be all the fixed values these use; scaling up and down for responsive behavior could require a lot of additional code.

Comment: You can use % values as the parent has height and width. The only fixed value is border radius.

Answer (score 2):

You shoud try something with the pseudo-element `:before` and `:after` applied on a single `div`.
You could do something like this :

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
} 

div:before, div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

div:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-left: solid 2px red;
  border-top: solid 2px red;
}

div:after {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  border-right: solid 2px red;
  border-bottom: solid 2px red;
}
```

And there is a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4pdLz8ba/).

Answer (score 2):

Since the pseudo element solution are already proposed, here is another one by using multiple linear/radial gradient background to achieve these border and no need to add extra element as it will be a part of the block since it's a background.

You will need exactly 3 elements :

1. a radial-gradient for the bottom/right curved border
2. a linear-gradient for the top solid line
3. a linear-gradient for the left solid line

You can easily adjust dimension and position of each background:

```css
#mainDiv {
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 0 0 80px 0;
  background-color: #3beadc;
  background: 
linear-gradient(to right, #000 50%, transparent 50%) 0px 0px / 20px 50px no-repeat, 
linear-gradient(to right, #000 50%, transparent 50%) 0px 0px / 90px 10px no-repeat, 
radial-gradient(circle at top left, transparent 29%, #000 30%) 130% 100%/34% 34% no-repeat, 
#3beadc
}
```

```html
<div id="mainDiv">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris suscipit quis est vel fringilla. Quisque eget tellus sed est vulputate varius. Quisque scelerisque lobortis molestie. Ut libero lorem, consequat quis commodo et, porttitor et sapien. Donec
    tristique purus eget nunc tincidunt ornare. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla consequat pellentesque pharetra. Donec imperdiet ex metus. Vestibulum nulla ligula, semper vel odio ut, ornare pellentesque arcu. Sed neque
    lectus, fermentum non ultricies id, sollicitudin eget turpis.</p>
</div>
```

### If you want more

You can also add more border to the other corner easily with this solution:

```css
#mainDiv {
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 0 0 80px 0;
  background-color: #3beadc;
  background: 
linear-gradient(to right, #000 50%, transparent 50%) 0px 0px / 20px 50px no-repeat, 
linear-gradient(to right, #000 50%, transparent 50%) 0px 0px / 90px 10px no-repeat,
linear-gradient(to right, #000 50%, transparent 50%) 0px 100% / 90px 10px no-repeat,
linear-gradient(to right, #000 50%, transparent 50%) 0px 100% / 20px 50px no-repeat,
linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%, #000 50%) 100% 0px / 90px 10px no-repeat,
linear-gradient(to right, transparent 50%, #000 50%) 100% 0px / 20px 50px no-repeat,
radial-gradient(circle at top left, transparent 29%, #000 30%) 130% 100%/34% 34% no-repeat,
#3beadc
}
```

```html
<div id="mainDiv">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris suscipit quis est vel fringilla. Quisque eget tellus sed est vulputate varius. Quisque scelerisque lobortis molestie. Ut libero lorem, consequat quis commodo et, porttitor et sapien. Donec
    tristique purus eget nunc tincidunt ornare. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla consequat pellentesque pharetra. Donec imperdiet ex metus. Vestibulum nulla ligula, semper vel odio ut, ornare pellentesque arcu. Sed neque
    lectus, fermentum non ultricies id, sollicitudin eget turpis.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shield like div with text inside like so
https://codepen.io/proevilz/pen/QaqNQx

```css
.main {
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
 position:relative;
 top:-180px;
}
.main p {
 text-align:center;
 margin:0;
}
.left {
 width:100px;
 position:relative;
 height:200px;
 left:2px;
 border-bottom-left-radius:100px;
 border-left:1px solid red;
 border-bottom:1px solid red;
 border-top: 1px solid red;
 display:inline-block;
}
.right {
 position:relative;
     border-top: 1px solid red;
 display:inline-block;
 width:100px;
 height:200px;
 right:2px;
 border-bottom-right-radius:100px;
 border-right:1px solid red;
 border-bottom:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="main">
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium quibusdam corporis dolor nesciunt repellendus perspiciatis temporibus rem.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but I don't want the whole shield - only a partial one similar to the image I included. Top left and bottom right only.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the borders with other absolutely position elements:

```css
#mainDiv {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background: #3beadc;
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
}

.cornerBorder {
  position: absolute;
  height: 15%;
  width: 15%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid black;
  border-top: 5px solid black;
}

.roundedBorder {
  position: absolute;
  height: 15%;
  width: 15%;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-right: 5px solid black;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainDiv">
  <div class="cornerBorder"></div>
  <p>Shield borders</p>
  <div class="roundedBorder"></div>
</div>
```