# How to add grey vertical lines in HTML page

Tags: html, css

I wanted to add some vertical lines to my webpage which I have displayed in  (image 1) In the top white box with the three columns I have managed to add the grey lines however I want them to be position like they are in image 2,

I also want to add grey vertical lines in the bottom text box, I tried to use the same method for the bottom white box with the 5 columns and would like it to look like image 2 
I have attached a JS fiddle with my current code in it, any help would be greatly appreciated!

https://jsfiddle.net/2j4b4bdn/1/

[image]
[image]

```
  p.text3 {
           position:fixed;
          bottom:23rem; 
          text-align:center; 
         width:160px;
           font-size:16px;
            font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
               right:42rem;
       }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to declare a size/partial border to a box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835142/any-way-to-declare-a-size-partial-border-to-a-box)

Comment: HI Temani Thanks for the reply, Does that allow you to position the lines vertically?

Comment: yes you have to simply adjust the postion of the pseudo element , and i advice to check all the answer and not only the accepted one, to get more ways

Comment: div {width:350px; height:100px; background:lightgray; position:relative; margin:20px;}
div:after{content:''; width:2px; height:120px; background:gray; position:absolute; bottom:-6px; } is there a way to put that on the right hand side as it is on the left?

Comment: simply add `right:0` :)

Comment: your element is absolute position so you can adjust its positon using top/left/right/bottom you can even use negative value to make it outside

Comment: thats perfect! so do I add both of those divs, to where the text is and then it will position itself on the right hand side of the text?

Comment: yes that's, simply don't forget to have the divs position:relative

Comment: so like so?  <div class="pt-inner-wrap">     
    <img src="tablet.png" style="height:50px;">                 .pt-inner-wrap {
        color: #ecf0f1;
        height: 200px;
        text-align: center;
        color: black;
        border-right: 3px solid #d4d4d4; 
        
        }                                                                                                                  div:after{content:''; width:2px; height:120px; background:gray; position:absolute; bottom:-6px; right:0

Answer (score 1):

Copy the following code and edit it in the way you want.
Replace the dummy texts with your images and buttons. remember to adjust the size of buttons and images because the column width varies with the contents.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container vertical-divider">
  <div class="column one-third">
    <h3>Mobiles & Smart Phones</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sit amet vestibulum libero. Proin semper sapien et odio mattis ornare vel ac metus. Fusce venenatis risus a justo vestibulum, eu efficitur ipsum ornare. Duis turpis lectus, laoreet ut gravida sit amet, imperdiet et nunc. Curabitur volutpat ultrices erat, et tempus dolor sodales at. In porttitor nisi et magna facilisis pulvinar. Sed aliquam nisl in nisl mattis, eu consectetur sem condimentum.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column one-third">
    <h3>i pads & tablets</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sit amet vestibulum libero. Proin semper sapien et odio mattis ornare vel ac metus. Fusce venenatis risus a justo vestibulum, eu efficitur ipsum ornare.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column one-third">
    <h3>Laptops & Mac Books</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sit amet vestibulum libero.</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container vertical-divider">
  <div class="column" align="center">
    <h3>Laptops and Mac Books</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sit amet vestibulum libero. Proin semper sapien et odio mattis ornare vel ac metus. Fusce venenatis risus a justo vestibulum, eu efficitur ipsum ornare. Duis turpis lectus, laoreet ut gravida sit amet, imperdiet et nunc. Curabitur volutpat ultrices erat, et tempus dolor sodales at. In porttitor nisi et magna facilisis pulvinar. Sed aliquam nisl in nisl mattis, eu consectetur sem condimentum.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
<div class="container vertical-divider">
<div class="column one-fifths">
    <h3>Little Text</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br> consectetur adipiscing<br> Donec sit amet vestib</p>
</div>
  <div class="column one-fifths">
    <h3>Little Text</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br> consectetur adipiscing<br> Donec sit amet vestib</p>
</div>
  <div class="column one-fifths">
    <h3>Little Text</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br> consectetur adipiscing<br> Donec sit amet vestib</p>
</div>
  <div class="column one-fifths">
    <h3>Little Text</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br> consectetur adipiscing<br> Donec sit amet vestib</p>
</div>
  <div class="column one-fifths">
    <h3>Little Text</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br> consectetur adipiscing<br> Donec sit amet vestib</p>
</div>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.vertical-divider{
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
}

.vertical-divider:after {
    clear: both;
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.vertical-divider .column:not(:first-child):after, .vertical-divider .columns:not(:first-child):after{
    background: #DDDDDD;
    bottom: 0;
    content: " ";
    margin-left: -10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 1px;
}

/* Very simple grid for example */
.container { position: relative; width: 960px; margin: 20px auto; padding: 0; }

.container .column, .container .columns { float: left; display: inline; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px; }

.container .one-third.column { width: 300px; }

.container .two-thirds.column { width: 620px; }
```

Hope you got your answer

Comment: Hi Binara thanks for the reply! I Just tried to add that to my code and it didn't work would you mind editing the js fiddle I uploaded?

Comment: OK sure I'll try

Comment: Thanks! im trying to get the vertcial lines to look like the second image! :)

Comment: any luck @binara?

Comment: Check this fiddle out. didn't do anything but, add @BinaraMedawatta 's code to the fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/41492/

Comment: Did some modifications to the fiddle. Check this out. this is more responsive and accurate. 
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/41493/

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't try it out, but the way @sanjithedward did is OK.