# How to change border width

Tags: html, css

I have a select box like bellow :

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true" name="color[]" title="موردی انتخاب نشده">

<option class="" style="border-bottom:2px solid; border-color:red" value="">قرمز</option>
<option class="" style="border-bottom:2px solid; border-color:black" value="">مشکی</option>
<option class="" style="border-bottom:2px solid; border-color:white" value="">سفید</option>


</select>
```

and I want to have line under each text of option but not like bellow

[image]

Because it is full width but I want to have line just under the text e.g. "قرمز"

I have tried witdh but it was not a good way because I want to have an option with full width clickable.

Comment: try background like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48103289/8620333

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To limit the undeline to the text only, use `text-decoration` instead of border. (You may need to use a suitable font-family which has no underline overlap with Persian characters):

```css
option {text-decoration: underline;}
```

```html
<select style="width:100%;" class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true" name="color[]" title="موردی انتخاب نشده">
<option value="" style="color:red;text-decoration-color: red;">قرمز</option>
<option value="" style="color:black;text-decoration-color: black;">مشکی</option>
<option value="" style="color:#aaaaaa;text-decoration-color: aaaaaa;">سفید</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution is using `Text-decoration` in CSS:

```
<option class="" style="text-decoration:underline;" value="">قرمز</option>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/yotking789/pen/KKwXpVg)

Answer (score 0):

use this div {border-width: thin;}
some property:-

### Value  |    Description

medium |    Specifies a medium border. This is default
thin   |    Specifies a thin border 
thick  |    Specifies a thick border
length |    Allows you to define the thickness of the border. Read about length units  |
initial|    Sets this property to its default value. Read about initial 
inherit|    Inherits this property from its parent element. Read about inherit

or you may use this

```
h1{
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 15px;
}
```