# Lay <HR> on top of a box in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a specific box style that I'm trying to accomplish and it's got me stumped. Here is a reference image:

[box with border and additional line styling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFnlB.png)

A few items, first and foremost, I'm beginning to learn responsive design and I've been able to accomplish this but as soon as I start to resize it breaks. I would like it the box and hr to work all as one item.

What I've tried: 
 - Box with border
 - HR styled within the box div and outside
 - HR with Z-Index

Here is the code:

```css
#valuesContainer {
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ccc;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font: Source;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 8%;
  padding: 5%;
  line-height: 1;
}

#valueTitle {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font: Source;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 22px;
}

#hrTop {
  width: 30vh;
  color: red;
  border-top: 5px solid #E7503D;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: -.2%;
  margin-top: -.75%;
  z-index: 999;
}

#hrTopRight {
  border: none;
  border-left:  5px solid #E7503D;
  height: 10vw;
  width:  1px;
  margin-top: -16%;
}
```

```html
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <div id="valuesContainer" class="box">
          <hr id="hrTop"align="right">
          <h1 id="valueTitle">Title</h1>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod                 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Feugiat scelerisque                 varius morbi enim nunc. 
          </p>
          <hr id="hrTopRight"align="right">
        </div>
      </div>
```

I'm not entirely sure I'm going about this the right way, but any help would greatly appreciate it. I have tried to search around and this is as far as I've been able to get with the information I found.'

UPDATE:
I couldn't see a way to award this answer since it was a comment. But I believe I may have found a much better way of doing this without using an HR tag.

> t looks like you are using
>
> ---
>
> to decorate the box and not to indicate a separation in your content (since they are at the very start and end). You can use a pseudo-element on your #valuesContainer instead to layer a box on top with absolute positioning (make sure #valuesContainer is relatively positioned).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any way to declare a size/partial border to a box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835142/any-way-to-declare-a-size-partial-border-to-a-box)

Comment: It looks like you are using `<hr>` to decorate the box and not to indicate a separation in your content (since they are at the very start and end). You can use a pseudo-element on your `#valuesContainer` instead to layer a box on top with absolute positioning (make sure `#valuesContainer` is relatively positioned).

Comment: I really like this method, seems easier to use versus using an <hr> as a decoration. I've been able to implement it, but I'm having some issues getting the desired effect. Specifically the right side box-shadow. This is what code looks like now.

`.topLine {
  position: relative;
}

.topLine::before {
  box-shadow: 3px -3px 0 3px #E7503D;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 59%;
  content: "";
  width: 40%;
}
`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `position: absolute` and `relative` on the parent `div`

```css
#valuesContainer {
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #ccc;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font: Source;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 8%;
  padding: 5%;
  line-height: 1;
   position: relative;
}

#valueTitle {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font: Source;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 22px;
}

#hrTop {
  width: 30vh;
  color: red;
  border-top: 5px solid #E7503D;
 
    position: absolute;
top: -17px;
    right: -7px;
    z-index: -999999;
}

#hrTopRight {
  border: none;
  border-left:  5px solid #E7503D;
  height: 10vw;
  width:  1px;
  position: absolute;
    top: -14px;
    right: -8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        <div id="valuesContainer" class="box">
          <hr id="hrTop"align="right">
          <h1 id="valueTitle">Title</h1>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod                 tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Feugiat scelerisque                 varius morbi enim nunc. 
          </p>
          <hr id="hrTopRight"align="right">
        </div>
      </div>
```