# Half colored border on top and right using css

Tags: css

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dt4QN.png

I would like to design my backgroud pciture as like above image. Here the issue is about bringing border with 3 different colors.
**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: from the first duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61913549/8620333

Comment: from the second duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48103289/8620333