# Border above/under title offset

Tags: html, css

Border like this:
[image: border like this]

I tried this, but the problem is that title is moved when this css is used. What would be better solution?

```css
h2:before {
    display: inline-block;
    content: "";
    border-top: 0.2rem solid black;
    width: 25rem;
    margin: 0 1rem;
    transform: translate(8rem,-4rem);
}
```

```html
<h2>ZADNJO PROJEKTI</h2>
```

Comment: can you add your html to it and make a code snippet

Comment: Please share a working code example people can make suggestions to. Please clearly state exactly what you need help with.

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48103289/8620333

Answer (score 0):

add `position: absolute` to your `h2:before` rule and `position: relative` to the `h2`, then it won't be moved.

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: absolute` for pseudoelements and `position: relative` on the `h2` element

```css
h2 {
   padding: 1rem 0;
   position: relative;
   text-align: center;
}

h2::before, h2::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 52%;
  height: 0.1rem;
  background: #000;
}


h2::before {
  top: 0; left: 0;
}

h2::after {
  bottom: 0; right: 0;
}
```

```html
<h2>Title</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

My idea is adding a span before and after h2 tag and then style to you spans.