# How to reduce the size of border-bottom?

Tags: html, css

I have the below CSS and it does display a border, however the border-bottom width takes the full size of the div.

```
.ng-dropdown-panel .ng-dropdown-panel-items .ng-option {
padding-top: 15px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
border-bottom: 3px solid #bbb;
}
```

I want the border-bottom to be like 80% and centered. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you provide more code and image how it looks now and how you want it to be?

Comment: @ishaba agree with you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Any way to declare a size/partial border to a box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835142/any-way-to-declare-a-size-partial-border-to-a-box)

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: lightblue;
  position: relative;
}

div:after {
  content: '';
  width: 80%;
  height: 2px;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: 20px
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thyapr4u/

Answer (score 2):

Maybe using a gradient for the border can get you something close to what you're looking for:

```css
.ng-option {
padding-top: 15px;
padding-bottom: 15px;
border-bottom: 3px solid;
border-image: radial-gradient(white, white, #bbb, white, white) 8;
}
```

```html
<div class="ng-option"></div>
```