# CSS Rectangle with one corner not connected

Tags: css, user-interface, sass, user-experience

Trying to replicate this design using css. The quotes are pngs. But can only find help for solid rectangles and more of a page corner folded to save a spot.[Design I'm trying to replicate with Css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOlP8.png)

Comment: from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48103289/8620333

Answer (score 0):

I gave them different colors so you could visualize what's happening easily.

```
.myDiv {
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 10px solid red;
  border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px;
  border-top: none;
  }
.myDiv::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  width: 40px; 
  background-color: orange;
  top:-10px;
  left:20px;
  border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
  }
```

[image: RESULT]