# Placing a transparent div with borders on top of another transparent div with borders

Tags: html, css

Please see the image below.

[contact-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6LCjl.png)

I want to make a contact container that has a square Contact header. I want the contact header in the middle of the container halfway out of the container. Problem is, both the header and the container have to be transparent and they have borders. The borders of the container cut right through the contact header. I'm having trouble removing the borders from inside the header.

```css
<style>* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.profile {
  width: 480px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

.contact {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid gray;
}

.contact {
  width: 40%;
  margin-top: -23px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.container {
  height: 380px;
}

.content {
  width: 400px;
  height: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.social {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

</style>
```

```html
<div class="profile">
  <section class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="contact">
        <h2>Contact</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <p class="about">Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae distinctio libero repudiandae consequatur qui, vel ad error animi doloremque magni cupiditate officia officiis et? Vel voluptatem reiciendis placeat cumque officiis!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="social">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Behance</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: A contact list can be seen as a form. As such it would even be semantically right to use a form. In this case, you can use `fieldset` and `legend` (you could also use it in any other case just not completely semantically correct).

Comment: @quasi this should not matter why the OP needs it to be transparent. Obviously, because the background should be visible which could be an image instead a solid color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `<fieldset>` and `<legend>`.

the legend is a title in a fieldset and the border of a fieldset will not go through the legend. The legend can be aligned with the margin.

```css
fieldset {
  border: 2px solid black;
  min-height: 50vh;
}

legend {
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px 20px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Contact</legend>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: That's awesome. Though it doesn't answer the title of the question *Placing a transparent div with borders on top of another transparent div with borders*

Comment: yes but it solves the issue as the title now can have a transparent background and fulfills the image requirements.

Answer (score -1):

Adapted from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835142/any-way-to-declare-a-size-partial-border-to-a-box), you could try this instead of border-top:

```css
body {
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/536/354');
  background-size: cover;
}

.header {
  width: 240px;
  border: 4px solid gray;
  height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.box {
  width: 350px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  border-left: 4px solid gray;
  border-right: 4px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 4px solid gray;
  padding: 20px;
}

.box:after {
  content: '';
  width: 60px;
  height: 4px;
  background: gray;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
}

.box:before {
  content: '';
  width: 60px;
  height: 4px;
  background: gray;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  title
</div>

<div class="box">

  content
</div>
```