# How to change the color of only part of the bar line (left end)?

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website and I'd like to separate Title and content using a border.
Simple border seems to be boring, so I tried to alter the bar color only left edge.
But, I couldn't do that.
It'd be nice if somebody help me.

Here is my HTML and CSS.

```
<div class="content">
    <h4><span>library guides</span></h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente, perspiciatis.</p>
    <a href="#">read more</a>
</div>
```

```
.content h4 span {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    font-weight: 900;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.content h4 span::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 0.5em;
    width: 620px;
    border-top: 2px solid rgb(225, 225, 225);
}
```

This is what I want to do. Please check an attachment photo.
[image: sample image]

Comment: This is also helpful. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835142/any-way-to-declare-a-size-partial-border-to-a-box)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way which I can think of getting it done is using ***[`::before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before)*** as below:

```css
.separator {
  position: relative;
  height: 1px;
  width: 70%; /* You can adjust this as per your need. */
  background-color: #d9dbda;
}

.separator::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 200%;
  width: 10%;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<div class="separator"></div>
```